# How good is my error?

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection

I'm trying to calculate how good are my measurements in machine learning! Let's say that I have five choices, and that error is 4, 2, 0.002, 3, 6. Naturally, I will pick third one for the hit, but I would like to say following:

- I'm X% certain that hit is third pick
- I'm Y% certain that hit is first (last) pick

Of course, X>>Y but I would like to know if is there some kind of statistics metric for this. I can always introduce my metric, but I'm interested is there some already known, so that I can avoid my explanation and just refer to particular metric?

The closest one is 'confidence interval', but that gives me the probability that my results are in some interval.

Comment: Requests to "avoid explanation" and a reluctance to use probability statements suggest an intention to use statistics to sanctify a result rather than understand or improve it.  That can make for a difficult conversation, because statisticians do not share this point of view.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend cross-validation; then, from all iterations, you can get not only average, but also an approximation of distribution of error, and you can use it to estimate the confidence interval.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid 'confidence interval'. I seek for some formal distance metric to interpret error. I know what I'm gone pick, I just need metric 'how sure am I' (in %).

Comment: It seems you need some since I'm not familiar with, so I hope someone else will give you a more satisfying answer; nevertheless getting/assuming distribution would be a inevitable starting point for such an analysis.

Comment: I have already used mine metric.
Thanks in any case.

Comment: Consider adding your solution as an answer; it is fair to do so, users that will read this in future will get the solution and you could earn some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

For the problem above, I have used a really simple metric.
I wanted to asses how good is my hit!
If I have, for example, errors 4, 2, 0.002, 3, 6 then I choose h1=0.002 as hit, and h2=2 as the closest error.
X/h1 + X/h2 = 100% => X/h1 and X/h2 is %.